# Discord.js TypeError: interaction.options is not a function - how to solve it?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, typeerror

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js');
const { formatDate } = require('../../events/utils/functions');

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('profil')
    .setDescription('Etiketlenen kişinin veya komutu birini etiketlemeden kullanan kişinin profilini gösterir.')
    .addUserOption(option => option.setName('kullanıcı').setDescription('Profilini görmek istediğiniz kullanıcıyı etiketleyin.')),
  async run(interaction) {
    try {
      const user = interaction.options.getUser('kullanıcı') || interaction.user;
      const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
      const roles = member.roles.cache
        .filter((r) => r.id !== interaction.guild.id)
        .map((r) => `<@&${r.id}>`);
      const joinedDate = formatDate(member.joinedAt);
      const accountCreatedDate = formatDate(user.createdAt);
      const nitroSince = member.premiumSince
        ? formatDate(member.premiumSince)
        : 'Nitro abonesi değil.';
      const boostCount = member.premiumSubscriptionCount;
      const boostTime = member.premiumSince
        ? `Sunucuya takviye vermeye başladığı tarih: ${formatDate(member.premiumSince)}`
        : 'Sunucuya takviye yapmıyor.';

      await user.fetch();

      let bannerURL = user.bannerURL({ size: 2048, format: 'png' });
      if (!bannerURL) {
        const attachment = new MessageAttachment(
          './icons/TFDMYS_Afis_Yok.png',
          'TFDMYS_Afis_Yok.png'
        );
        bannerURL = 'attachment://TFDMYS_Afis_Yok.png';
        interaction.reply({ files: [attachment] });
        return;
      }

      const badgesArray = user.flags.toArray();
      let badges = '';

      if (badgesArray.length > 0) {
        badges = badgesArray.map((badge) => getBadgeName(badge)).join(', ');
      } else {
        badges =
          'Bu TF Sakininin herhangi bir Discord rozeti veya unvanı bulunmuyor.';
      }

      function getBadgeName(badge) {
        switch (badge) {
          case 'HOUSE_BALANCE':
            return '<:TF_Rozet_HypeSquad_Denge:1108870588954591312> HypeSquad Denge Rozeti';
          case 'HOUSE_BRAVERY':
            return '<:TF_Rozet_HypeSquad_Cesaret:1108872353255006238> HypeSquad Cesaret Rozeti';
          case 'HOUSE_BRILLIANCE':
            return '<:TF_Rozet_HypeSquad_Gorkem:1108872425103429692> HypeSquad Görkem Rozeti';
          case 'EARLY_SUPPORTER':
            return '<:TF_Rozet_Erken_Destekci:1108872344379871293> Erken Dönem Destekçisi';
          case 'EARLY_VERIFIED_DEVELOPER':
            return '<a:TF_Rozet_E_Dogrulanmis_G_Hareket:1108872845011980309> Erken Doğrulanmış Geliştirici';
          case 'BUGHUNTER_LEVEL_1':
            return '<a:TF_Rozet_DC_Hata_Avcisi_Hareket:1108872887328321648> Hata Avcısı Seviye 1';
          case 'BUGHUNTER_LEVEL_2':
            return '<a:TF_Rozet_DC_Altin_Hata_Avcisi_H:1108872881812807781> Hata Avcısı Seviye 2';
          case 'VERIFIED_DEVELOPER':
            return '<a:TF_Ikon_Onay_Hareketli:1108872805421961306> Doğrulanmış Geliştirici';
          case 'DISCORD_EMPLOYEE':
            return '<a:TF_Rozet_Discord_Ekibi_Hareketli:1108872838796034198> Discord Personeli';
          case 'DISCORD_PARTNER':
            return '<:TF_Rozet_Discord_Ortagi_Sunucu_S:1108872870714671135> Discord Ortağı';
          case 'DISCORD_CERTIFIED_MODERATOR':
            return '<a:TF_Rozet_Mod_Akademisi_Mezunu_H:1108872821800710255> Discord Onaylı Moderatör';
          case 'ACTIVE_DEVELOPER':
            return '<a:TF_Rozet_Aktif_Gelistirici_H:1108872851542523965> Aktif Geliştirici';
          case 'VERIFIED_BOT':
            return '<a:TF_Ikon_Onay_Hareketli:1108872805421961306> Doğrulanmış Bot';
          case 'PARTNERED_SERVER_OWNER':
            return '<:TF_Rozet_Discord_Ortagi_Sunucu_S:1108872870714671135> Discord Ortağı Sunucu Sahibi';
          case 'EARLY_VERIFIED_BOT_DEVELOPER':
            return '<a:TF_Rozet_E_Dogrulanmis_G_Hareket:1108872845011980309> Erken Doğrulanmış Bot Geliştiricisi';
          case 'EARLY_VERIFIED_BOT':
            return '<a:TF_Ikon_Onay_Hareketli:1108872805421961306> Erken Doğrulanmış Bot';
          default:
            return badge;
        }
      }

      const embed = {
        color: '#500000',
        author: {
          name: `${user.username}#${user.discriminator}`,
          icon_url: user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
        },
        thumbnail: {
          url: user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
        },
        image: {
          url: bannerURL,
        },
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'Nitro Bilgisi',
            value: `${nitroSince} ${member.premiumSince ? '(Abonelik başlamasından bu yana)' : ''}`,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: 'Sunucuya Yapılan Takviye Sayısı',
            value: boostTime,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: 'Roller',
            value:
              roles.length > 0
                ? roles.join(' ')
                : 'Bu kullanıcının herhangi bir rolü yok.',
          },
          {
            name: 'Sunucuya Katılım Tarihi',
            value: joinedDate,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: 'Hesap Oluşturulma Tarihi',
            value: accountCreatedDate,
            inline: true,
          },
          {
            name: 'Rozetler',
            value: badges,
          },
        ],
        footer: {
          text: `${user.username}#${user.discriminator} | Profil Bilgisi`,
          icon_url: user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }),
        },
      };

      await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Hata oluştu:');
      console.trace(error);
    }
  },
};
```

Hi, I'm pretty new to this stuff and I'm getting an error I can't solve. This is the slash command code that will reflect some of the user's profile information to the embed message of my bot running with Discord.js version 13.15.1. The error I get is `TypeError: interaction.options is not a function` and I've been stuck on this error for a while. Thanks for your help!

I've tried everything I can to make sure the code doesn't error, checked my discord.js version, still can't seem to fix the problem.

What I expected to happen was that the code could properly respond to slash command requests without errors.

EDIT:

Detailed error with `console.trace()`:

`Hata oluştu: Trace: TypeError: interaction.options.getUser is not a function at Object.run (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\slash_commands\General\profil.js:12:40) at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\events\Guild\interactionCreate.js:13:23) at Client.emit (node:events:390:28) at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:83:12) at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36) at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:346:31) at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:493:22) at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:327:10) at callListener (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14) at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9) at Object.run (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\slash_commands\General\profil.js:143:15) at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\events\Guild\interactionCreate.js:13:23) at Client.emit (node:events:390:28) at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:83:12) at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36) at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:346:31) at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:493:22) at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:327:10) at callListener (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:290:14) at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\TFDMYS\TF - Temsili Sistem\TFTS - TF Temsili Sistemi\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:209:9)`

Comment: The error implies you're trying to call `interaction.options()`, which isn't present in the code you posted. Did you read the error? Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them! The error should tell you what line number it's coming from.

Comment: ah, I'm sorry, but a single line appears in the console as an error and that's "interaction.options is not a function"
he says, i really don't understand what i have to do exactly so i'm extremely new to this stuff. There are also different slash commands that contain inerations.options... in my bot, all of them reflect the same error in a single line to the console: TypeError: interaction.options is not a function

Comment: look for `interaction.options()` throughout your directory. `interaction.options` is an object and cannot be called, so remove the `()`

Comment: I tried what you said but if I delete `()`s how can I define "kullanıcı" with .getUser?

Comment: There is not enough information to help you because it's not clear what line is causing your error. You should use `console.log()` statements to both debug which lines of code are executing, as well as debug what is in variables. For example, once you find where you're trying to call `interaction.options()`you should `console.log(interactions)` to see what it is, rather than try to guess at the API. You should also review the discord API documentation to make sure you're using the library right.

Comment: The error you're getting should include both a line number and a stack trace. Read both to find the line the error is coming from. If you aren't getting a line number, something is probably catching the error, you could try finding that part of the code and doing more debugging there, like using `console.trace()`. You have not done enough debugging yet for us to be able to help you. Once you have done the required debugging, please edit your question to include the relevant details.

Comment: Hello again, sorry for my late reply. Thanks to `console.trace()` the details of the error seem to be revealed. I also examined the `discord.js` library, as far as I understand it shows usages as used in the code in general. I edited my question with the details we obtained. Thank you again.

Comment: i still need help, if anyone there. please

Comment: Have you tried using `console.log()` on the interaction variable. Is it *definitely* defined?